# How call rest api in command step in buildkite?

Tags: buildkite

[Here](https://buildkite.com/docs/apis/rest-api) is the rest documentation for buildkite and any request requires a auth token. Can this API be invoked from buildkite build somehow? Maybe some command that already grabbed token because it running inside Buildkite? or some additional step to get such a token?

Ot the only way is to go `https://buildkite.com/user/api-access-tokens` section and create token manually even when I use buildkite API inside buildkite step?

Comment: Can you provide some more information and context here please. What is it you are trying to do with the API? What endpoint are you trying to call?

Answer (score 1):

The REST API uses a different token from the agent when it's running inside a job. If you want to use the REST API from inside a job, you'll have to find a way to retrieve a REST API token in your builds, as it's a secret, you should manage access to it as such (e.g. don't just put it in pipeline's environment variables).

Once you have a job that has access to the REST API token, you can use it to call the REST API with a tool like CURL, or the [BK CLI](https://github.com/buildkite/cli).